# SEO: TYPO3 doesen't render <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

Tags: typo3, meta-tags

noticed that TYPO3 only renders the following tag combinations (depending on the settings):

```
<meta name = "robots" content = "noindex, nofollow">
<meta name = "robots" content = "noindex, follow">
<meta name = "robots" content = "index, nofollow">
```

It never renders this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
```

It just render nothing.

It's not a bug because this is how TYPO3 creates the tag:

```
if ($noIndex === 'noindex' || $noFollow === 'nofollow') {
  $manager = $metaTagManagerRegistry->getManagerForProperty('robots');
  $manager->addProperty('robots', implode(',', [$noIndex, $noFollow]));
}
```

Do i need this Tag when i have index and follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's the job of a search engine to index all available documents and to follow all links to get all documents it is the default behaviour.

Only if you want another behaviour you need to declare it.